# Is there a text editor which can display null bytes

Tags: gedit, text-editor

Not important to the question but I'm working with files output from a php script. These files contain null bytes (\00) which is actually part of the php output and should not be removed.

Up until now, I've been using gedit to view these files. It complains about the encoding but is usueful in that it highlights the null bytes. This only seems to work with small files though. Trying to open a larger file (15kb and that is still small) displays pure gibberish.

Is there another editor which is able to display (pure ASCII) files which contain unprintable characters? I'd much prefer an editor which replaces said bytes with the standard 'illegal character' (question mark set in a diamond glyph).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using **Hex Editor** for such purposes, as normal editors don't display [non-printing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Control_character)  unless its some side-effect or glitch.

I suggest [Bless](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bless) [image: Install Bless]:

[image: Bless Hex Editor]

And in console you can use [Midnight Commander's](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mc) [image: Install Midnight Commander] mcview - <kbd>F4</kbd> switches to hex mode:

[image]

Comment: While a hex editor is useful, it's a little overkill for my needs. Is there any way to switch it into text mode?

Comment: Scratch that, mcedit does exactly what I want :)